# Как сделать так что бы строка "Этот бот все ещё находится в разработке" писалась синим цветом?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
    # Получаем информацию о группе, в которой запущен бот
    group_info = bot.get_chat(message.chat.id)
    group_name = group_info.title

    # Отправляем сообщение с приветствием и информацией о боте
    message_text = f"Привет! Я новый телеграмм бот созданный для группы {group_name}. "
                   "<b>Этот бот все ещё находится в разработке</b>"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Comment: А такое разве есть в телеграмме? Насколько мне известно, нельзя менять цвет у текста.

Comment: Можете добавить ссылку на что-то, к примеру на свой ресурс, где уведомляется о разработке или на сам этот же бот. Тогда на некоторых устройствах (вроде, кроме IOS) оно будет отображаться синим. Реализовать это можно следующим образом: `<a href="ссылка">Этот бот все ещё находится в разработке</a>` А так, телеграм не предоставляет возможность изменения цвета текста.

Answer (score 0):

Если смотреть через desktop-версию приложения, то это делается вот так:

```
<code>Этот бот все ещё находится в разработке</code>
```

Comment: В моб. версии приложения он будет обычным цветом